LogQL query filter where two fields are equal
I have a json formatted log entry and want to filter to all those, where the field coverCurrency is equal to the field premiumCurrency.

I tried: {namespace="calculation-engine"} | json | line_format "{{.RequestContent}}" | json | __error__="" | premiumCurrency == coverCurrency but it doesn't work. I googled all day, but I am really stuck.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

IIUC, == (and other operators) in logql only supports comparison with constants. To work around this limitation you can use templating to introduce different label, and the filter by it. Something like this: | label_format flag=`{{ if eq .pCur .cCur }}yes{{end}}`|flag="yes"
